# What's wrong with my math on this wage-calculator?

Tags: java, math, calculator

I know this is more of a math oriented question, so I was hesitant to ask it, but I feel like you all could be of some help. Trying to get the calculations of the double time area of my code.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Wages {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        final double Rate = 9.32; // minimum wage
        final int Standard = 40; // working hours until time and a half 41-60
        final int Double = 60; // 61+ hours is overtime

        double pay = 0.0;

        System.out.print ("How many hours have you worked?: ");
        double Hours = kb.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        //Give out different pay grades depending on hours

        if (Hours > Double)
            /* Problem on this line: */
            pay = (Standard * Rate) + ((Standard+20) * (Rate * 1.5)) + ((Hours-Double) * (Standard * 2)); //Double pay**

        else if (Hours > Standard)
            pay = Standard * Rate + (Hours-Standard) * (Rate * 1.5); // Time and a half

        else {
            pay = Hours * Rate; // Standard
        }

        //Output earnings
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        System.out.println ("Earnings: " + fmt.format(pay));


}
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem located, what is the input, what is the output, what is the expected output?

Comment: Oops, my bad. It's in the if statement. It's the math there. For 65 hours, the total should be about $813 I believe, but I'm getting about $1,200.

Comment: Have you performed the calculation exactly as it is there on a calculator? How does it relate to your output in your program?

Comment: The problem is presumed to be located in the line which the asker attempted to print in **bold** lines by enclosing it into double asterisks

Comment: Sorry, kind of newer to this site. Well, when I did my math, I just did each chunk separately. (Standard working hours 0-40 at minimum wage, then time and a half, then double.) And my teacher did the same, but it was a few days ago. I just remember it was about $813 or so. And I know my math in this program is just way off.

Comment: This will not compile: **pay = (Standard * Rate) + ...

Comment: If you're referring to the asterisks, that was just me being dumb and not being able to bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the problem line:

```
pay = (Standard * Rate)
```

This pays 40 hours * $9.32. So far so good.

```
+ ((Standard+20) * (Rate * 1.5))
```

Here you add pay for another 60 hours at 1.5 time.

```
+ ((Hours-Double) * (Standard * 2));
```

And finally you pay $80/hr for every hour above 60, because you used `Standard` instead of `Rate`.

What you meant was:

```
pay = (Standard * Rate) + ((Double-Standard) * (Rate * 1.5)) + ((Hours-Double) * (Rate * 2));
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm just not really good with math, so thanks for breaking it down. Just stupid errors with being half awake! :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be (Standard - 20), no?  Also, it should be (Rate * 2).

```
pay = (Standard * Rate) + ((Standard - 20) * (Rate * 1.5)) + ((Hours - Double) * (Rate * 2));
```

Comment: No, that's the time and a half part of the equation. 0-40 hours are standard, 41-60 are time and a half, 61+ is double.

Comment: @jacobl But it's only time and a half for 20 hours, right?  Not 60.

Comment: `Standard - 20` is only coincidentally correct; should just be `20`. For non-40 values of Standard this would be broken.